# Cron vs Programmatic Repetition?

Tags: cron

I want to have a Python script to be run periodically every x minutes. Is it better to have a cron kick it off or have a sleep-run cycle within Python? I believe the following are the points to consider to make the decision. Please let me know if I have missed any. I guess this does not just relate to Python but is applicable in a more general sense too.

- Error/Exception handling - if the script explodes, the cron can always kick it off again. For the script, I can still have a global try-catch and work around this.
- Memory leaks over multiple runs are better for Cron to handle as it will accumulate on a repeatedly running Python script
- Thread overlap is my biggest concern on using Cron - I dont want to have multiple instances of the script running and I am not 100% sure if the run will complete within the inter-cron interval. In such a scenario, I felt the Python model works better than the Cron.

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments point you towards the cron solution.

The cron overlap issue is easily handled using a semaphore/lock.  Linux comes with the flock command for example that is simple and easy to use in a shell script.  See http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock for an example.

In your bash script, if you start with this code:

```
exec 200>/var/run/yourscript.lock
flock -n 200 || exit 1
// exec your script here
```

The script will either establish an exclusive lock, or exit with a code of 1.  You follow this with the execution of your python script.  This protects you from overlapping runs.  The file handle is released when the bash script ends.

Answer (score 0):

A proposed daemon (python) script is a viable solution. You can use a python library to ease the task.

To avoid memory leaks you should execute the periodical python script as a separate process via subprocess library and catch the exit status.

Comment: An interesting statement. Especially since the OP did say absolutely nothing about "his case"...

Comment: "(...)I am not 100% sure if the run will complete within the inter-cron interval.(...)"

Comment: There are easy and proven controls for this scenario. Actually that is the case with _all_ usages of cron in theory. The question is extremely vague in what the actual goal of this is, the environment, the requirements. That is why I stumble about your statement.

Comment: You argue about semantics. Given the vague details a daemon script is no worse than a cron job.